# Class Segment Representing a Line Segment in a Plane?

Tags: python

The problem we were given is to create a class `Segment` that represents a line segment in the plane and supports these methods:

- `__init__()`: constructor that takes as input a pair of Point objects that represent the endpoints of the line segment;
- `length()`: returns the length of the segment;
- `slope()` returns the slope of the segment or `None` if the slope is unbounded.

```
>>> p1 = Point(3,4)
>>> p2 = Point()
>>> s = Segment (p1, p2)
>>> s.length()
5.0
>>> s.slope()
0.75
```

I am confused on how I would get it to print the slope as well as the length. I feel like I would know how to do this if I just had to create a function that returned these results, but being able to transform these into classes is what is really confusing me.

Comment: I feel like this is homework.

Comment: Consider that classes are just functions, with one of the arguments first. that is `s.length()` is exactly the same as `length(s)`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to object-oriented programming, I may throw around a few terms with which you are not familiar: if that's the case, I suggest you look up any words you don't know ;)

The difference between a method and a regular function is the fact that the method is "owned" by the class. A method is basically a function which is only performed on (usually objects of) that class. In python, you declare methods by putting them in the class body, indented once, like so:

```
class MyClass:

    def myMethod(self):
        ...
```

One thing to keep in mind is the keyword `self` - it refers to the *instance* of that class, i.e. the particular object. You don't pass it as an argument in parentheses, though - it's that `s` before the `.` in your example. When you *instantiated* `s` by doing `s = Segment(p1, p2)`, you created an *instance* of the class `Segment` called `s`. You must pass `self` as the first argument to your class methods; how else are you supposed to know upon which object to operate?

`__init__()` is a special method which defines how to create a new object of that class. You call it by typing the class name, followed by your arguments in parentheses as if the class name were a method. In your example that's `Point(3, 4)` and `Segment(p1, p2)`.

Normally, you might type `s.p1` to get the first point of a `Segment`, but in your method bodies, you don't know what `s` is, since the classes are declared before `s` is instantiated. You do, however, know to pass `self`, so you would type `self.p1` to get the `p1` of whichever `Segment` to which you are referring.

Do you already have the `Point` class defined somewhere? Look at its code for examples.

If you want some guided exercises, I suggest you check out [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-WL8e4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096). It's very elementary but it will get the job done.